# Mongoose.js - populating a property of each item in collection with results of an instance method

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm having a spot of bother with Mongoose.js - I have a Category schema, and a Projects schema. Each category can have any number of projects, and each project has both a `type` and a `relatedProjects` array that lists projects with the same `type`. The `relatedProjects` field has to be random, and limited to 4 - but I couldn't do this with Mongoose and instead sort the entire results of `relatedProjects` outside of the schema using lodash.

This is the instance method I'm using:

```
ProjectSchema.methods.findRelatedProjects = function(callback) {
  return this.model('Project')
    .where('type').equals(this.type) // find projects with the same type
    .where('_id').ne(this._id) // exclude this project from the result set
    .select('_id')
    .exec(callback);
};
```

This is how I fetch the `relatedProjects` for a single project (the promise library I'm using is [when.js](https://github.com/cujojs/when/blob/master/docs/api.md)):

```
router.get('/:id', function(req, res) {
  var data = {};
  when(Project.findOne({ _id: req.params.id }).exec())
  .then(function(project) {
    data.project = project;
    return node.call(data.project.findRelatedProjects.bind(data.project));
  })
  .then(function(relatedProjects) {
    var project = data.project.toObject();
    project.relatedProjects = _.first(_.shuffle(relatedProjects), 4);
    res.send(project);
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    res.send(error);
  });
});
```

However, when I try to populate that field after fetching an entire collection, be it `Categories` or `Projects`, I run into trouble. Either the results that get sent back are completely empty (though `console.log`'ing the results gives me the right data), or it comes back without the `relatedProjects` field set.

Here is code that returns completely empty:

```
router.get('/content.json', function(req, res) {
  var data = {};
  when(Category.find({}).lean().exec())
  .then(function(categories) {
    data.categories = categories;
    return when.map(categories, function(category, i) {
      return when(Project.find({ category: category._id }).exec())
    })
    .then(function(projects) {
      return when.map(projects, function(project, j) {
        return node.call(project.findRelatedProjects.bind(project))
          .then(function(relatedProjects) {
            project.relatedProjects = relatedProjects;
            return project;
          })
      })
    });
  })
  .then(function(categories) {
    res.send({ categories: categories });
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    res.send(error);
  });
});
```

It's worth noting that `when.map` iterates asynchronously, but I have tried looping regularly only to receive the same result.

This code returns all the data, except for the fact that each `relatedProjects` instance is completely empty. (`console.log(relatedprojects)` gives me the right data, though):

```
router.get('/content.json', function(req, res) {
  var data = {};
  when(Category.find({}).populate('projects').lean().exec())
  .then(function(categories) {
    data.categories = categories;
    categories.forEach(function(category) {
      category.projects.forEach(function(project) {
        Project.findOne({ _id: project.id }, function(error, dbproject) {
          dbproject.findRelatedProjects(function(error, relatedprojects) {
            project.relatedProjects = relatedprojects;
          })
        });
      });
    });
    res.send({categories: categories});
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    res.send(error);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a few issues. Two of them were consistent through refactoring. The first issue is that wrapping a mongoose promise with `when.js` was screwing things up slightly. The second issue was that the `res.send` was being called before the documents were populated with the correct data. This code fixed the problem:

```
router.get('/content.json', function(req, res) {
  var data = { categories: [] };
  when.map(Category.find({}).exec(), function(category, i) {
    data.categories[i] = category;
    data.categories[i].projects = [];
    return when.map(Project.find({ category: category._id }).exec(), function(project, j) {
      data.categories[i].projects[j] = project.toObject();
      return node.call(project.findRelatedProjects.bind(project)).then(function(relatedProjects) {
        data.categories[i].projects[j].relatedProjects = _.first(_.shuffle(relatedProjects), 4);
      });
    });
  })
  .then(function() {
    res.send(data);
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    res.send(error);
  });
});
```